# Inform user that email is invalid using Django's Password Reset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am using the built-in django password reset functionality. [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm) states:

> If the email address provided does not exist in the system, this view won’t send an email, but the user won’t receive any error message either. This prevents information leaking to potential attackers. If you want to provide an error message in this case, you can subclass PasswordResetForm and use the password_reset_form argument.

However, in my case it's more important to show an error message when a user tries to reset using the wrong username.

I understand what I need to do but I don't know what to write in the form subclassing PasswordResetForm.

**What should the form subclassing PasswordResetForm contain?**

Thank you.

Comment: Just override the clean method for the username field.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So I finally figured it out myself. Here's my implementation:

```
class EmailValidationOnForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            raise ValidationError("There is no user registered with the specified email address!")

        return email
```

You also need to add `{'password_reset_form': EmailValidationOnForgotPassword}` to `urls.py`. Here's an example:

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
    {'post_reset_redirect': '/user/password/reset/done/',
     'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
     'password_reset_form': EmailValidationOnForgotPassword},
    name="password_reset"),
```

Comment: You probably want a case-insensitive match, and active users only: that's when the form doesn't send an email. Also, `exists()` would be slightly faster than `get()`, so it would be `if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists(): raise ValidationError`

Comment: Excellent observations, thank you! I have updated the answer.

Comment: Here I raised ValidationError message in my code but it will not show in my screen :( please help me. I import ValidationError from ' from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError '

Answer (score 5):

For later versions of Django such as Django 2.1 there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52947335/9177173) with slightly modified code.

```
#forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class EmailValidationOnForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            msg = _("There is no user registered with the specified E-Mail address.")
            self.add_error('email', msg)
        return email
```

And

```
#urls.py
from accounts.forms import EmailValidationOnForgotPassword

path('accounts/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=EmailValidationOnForgotPassword), name='password_reset'),
```

Please be aware that this can be used to obtain usernames/e-mails. One way to **reduce** this issue is to respond with a `429 Too Many Requests` as soon an user tries 3 different E-Mails. This can be achived using for example [django-ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/django-ratelimit/)

Answer (score 1):

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
```

```
class EmailValidationOnForgotPassword(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not NewUser.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("There is no user registered with the specified email address!")
        return email
```

urls.py

```
from users.forms import EmailValidationOnForgotPassword
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('users.urls',namespace='users')),
 
    path('reset_password', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(form_class=EmailValidationOnForgotPassword), name='reset_password'),
    path('reset_password_sent',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

password_reset_form.html

```
 <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}

   {% if form.errors %}
   {% for field in form %}
   {% for error in field.errors %} 
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %} 

   <div class="form-group">
      <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
      {{ form.email|attr:"type:email"|attr:"class:form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Email" }}
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">SUBMIT</button>
   </div>
</form>
```