# Password Reset - Validation Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using In-built reset password of django. Now the problem is that when i enter a email which does not exists in database, It does not give error that `email does not exist`

```
    # Reset Password
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset/done/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_done.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('password-reset-complete/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
         template_name='commons/password_reset/password_reset_complete.html'
     ),
     name='password_reset_complete'),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inform user that email is invalid using Django's Password Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734185/inform-user-that-email-is-invalid-using-djangos-password-reset)

Answer (score 0):

`PasswordResetConfirmView` method `get_user()` hides a number of failures, and one of them is `UserModel.DoesNotExist`. If you want to raise that error, you should create your own view inheriting from `PasswordResetConfirmView` and override `get_user()` there.